# Laravel5: Receiving empty result for select on second database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'll try to create a small application in Laravel5 and for that I have 2 databases.

I did set up a second connection in the `config/databases.php` file and specified `protected $connection = 'blog'` in my `Category` model.

I now try to select all my categories with `$categories = Category::all();` but in the query log for the `blog` connection, I'll receive an empty set even while the table is holding 6 datasets. I can't find the reason, why it doesn't return them.

```
// My model
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'blog';
    protected $visible = ['id', 'name'];
}

// My controller
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function list()
    {
        DB::connection('blog')->enableQueryLog();
        $categories = Category::all();
        // $categories = DB::connection('blog')->table('categories')->select('*')->get();
        Log::info(DB::connection('blog')->getQueryLog());

        return view('category.list')->with(compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried with the all method and I tried with the manual way, both doesn't return the datasets of the table.

My log of `storage/logs/laravel.log`:

```
[2016-06-01 21:28:46] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `categories`',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'time' => 0.45000000000000001,
  ),
)
```

Can anybody help me out?

Regards

Comment: Further information: The new app I try to create is an administration panel while the first app I created was a small blog software which I now like to manage with the new external administration panel, that's why there are 2 databases (one for my blog application and one for the administration panel).

Answer (score 0):

You're using eloquent as I see, did you declare the protected $visible fields in your model?

Try this too

```
return view('view')->with(compact('name_of_your_variable');
```

Comment: I now declared the variable like this: `protected $visible = ['id', 'name'];` but I still don't get any results from the select query.

The `return view('view')->....` does not help 'bout the select problem, does it?

Comment: did you try the return as i post it? in your .env what is your default database name is the same that you're using in your database.php?

Comment: No, I'm just working with the laravel.log file in `storage/logs` folder. I try now to create a small view for that.

Comment: So, no result with the view thing... Since I use 2 databases, I removed the database thing completly from the .env file.

Comment: I put my current model and controller to the start post.

Comment: I'm really sure that you check this post [link] (http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections) I made it just two days ago and run well maybe is a config needed

Comment: I now tested several ways, but I don't get any results for the select :/

Comment: You said that you have 2 databases right? and then you specified one in the model, are you sure, that there is the correct enviroment? If you run them in a migration did you specified the correct database to create the table? at least can I see your database.config? put some dummy data if you want only to check that everything is well

Comment: As I said, the second connection is from another Laravel application, it's just copied, so it should work well (MySQL server is running on localhost, both databases exist). [Pastebin - database.php](http://pastebin.com/s53afiJY)

Comment: If the connection works well in the other project connect this one will have to work too... I have multiple projects in different enviroments al connected to the same database and works well even I tried the last day connect my localhost and the one in a server and all went ok... But there's no error from connection just the data doesn't show at all... like if there's no rows in the table that's really weirdo. Check the dafaults in database.php maybe there is changing the destiny

Comment: It's really weird that there is no data selected and I can't figure out why. I tried so many ways now but I can't get it to work.